# AVFoundation & iOS - AVAssetWriterInput Captures And Crop A Square Video With Selected Position (Not Center Position)

Tags: objective-c, video, avfoundation, movie

Thank you for seeing this question.
I faced a problem that try to crop a square with selected place.
I completed to make a square capture, but I gave up to crop favorite place.
`AVAssetWriterInput` alway capture the square at "Center"

In my opinion, `AVAssetWriterInput`'s `transform` is a key to solve this problem, but 
I couldn't complete, even I tried any pattern which I could imagine.

I understand `transform` can control rotate of video, but can it control position?

Please help me to work out this problem. Thank you.

[image: purpose style]

Answer (score 1):

`CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` will make a transform that can change the position for you.